# Blazor InputText with Required attribute but Disabled

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly, blazor-editform

So I have a model, other properties removed for brevity:

```
public class OutOfLimitReasonViewModel
{
  
  [Required]
  public int ReasonId { get; set; }
  
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Other Reason is required")]
  public string OtherReason { get; set; }
}
```

Of course I have an `EditForm` on the `.razor` page and the `InputText` I care about looks like this:

```
<InputText @bind-Value="model.OtherReason" class="form-control" disabled="@(!OtherReasonRequired)" />
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.OtherReason)" />
```

There is also a `select` that has the list of available `Reason` objects, one of which is `Other`.
I do have a property called `OtherReasonRequired` which graphically does what I want (either Enable or Disable the input based on if the selected `Reason == "Other"`) so that code works:

```
public bool OtherReasonRequired
{
  get
  {
    var result = false;

    if (model.ReasonId > 0)
    {
      var reason = Reasons.Find(x => x.Id == model.ReasonId);
      result = reason.Reason == "Other";
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

This works perfectly if I select `Other` and give `OtherReason` a value, the Save/Submit button is valid and it works.

My issue is when I have NOT selected `Other`. Graphically, the `InputField` does get disabled and grayed out. But the Save/Submit believes the model is invalid because there is no value in the `OtherReason` field.

Is there something I can do to get this to work?

Would love to have a dynamic attribute called `RequiredIf`.

*But logically to me, I see this as a **bug**. If a control is disabled, it's value is irrelevant in my mind.*

Comment: Don't get so hung up on doing things the default way.  Instead of using a "Required" annotation, you can just check your form submission.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Thank you, of course that will work, but it breaks the UX and consistency when now I have to pop a message box or programmatically show the invalid message. Just not ideal. I was

Comment: In the context of a large site, those extra 4 lines of code in your OnValidSubmit handler really shouldn't matter.  But more of a problem is the semantics you're trying to force-- you have a "Required, maybe, kind of but not really" field.  Rather than disable a textbox that is always there even when not needed, it would be better IMO to have a 2-stage selection: 1st pick the problem, then IF the problem is other, display your input and validate it (say with a minimum 10 chars requirement).  They shouldn't be part of the same model, because many selections won't require text input at all.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 true. IMO disabled should rule. Moving on, thanks for your time.

Comment: You are using the Data Annontations Validator which is VERY basic.  You are looking for  conditional validation.  Search further afield for more sophisticated validation.  You may need to write your own rules.  If you get stuck search for my name and Blazor validation for how to write your own,  It's not that difficult.  It's not a bug, just a feature you want that isn't implemented!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following.  I don't use any of the built-in Data Annotation, but it's still very easy to check the input and let the user know what I want them to do:

```
<EditForm Model="@DisplayModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" >
        <InputRadioGroup TValue=int? @bind-Value=DisplayModel.ReasonID>
            @for (int i=1; i< Reasons.Count(); i++){
                <InputRadio Value=Reasons[i].ID /> @Reasons[i].Description <br/>
            }
            <InputRadio Value=0 />Other <br/>
        </InputRadioGroup>
        <input @bind=DisplayModel.OtherText disabled=@((DisplayModel.ReasonID??1) !=0 ) />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div class="text-danger">@DisplayMessage</div>
    </EditForm>

@code {
    string DisplayMessage="";

    class Reason { public int? ID; public string? Description; }
    List<Reason> Reasons = new List<Reason> {
            new Reason { ID = 0, Description = "Other"},
            new Reason { ID = 1, Description = "You're lame" },
            new Reason { ID = 2, Description = "I'm too busy" }
    };
    class MyDisplayModel
    {
        public int? ReasonID;
        public string OtherText="";
    }
    MyDisplayModel DisplayModel = new MyDisplayModel();
    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        if(DisplayModel.ReasonID is not null) if (DisplayModel.ReasonID==0) if (DisplayModel.OtherText == "")
            {
                DisplayMessage = "You must type a description of your issue.";
                StateHasChanged();
                await Task.Delay(1500);
                DisplayMessage = "";
            }
    }
}
```